# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect - virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have virtualenvwrapper-win installed with python3.6 on win7.
When using it, and providing path to another version of python I get these error messages:

```
> mkvirtualenv mynew_env --python=d:\python\python35\python.exe
Running virtualenv with interpreter d:\python\python35\python.exe
Using base prefix 'd:\\python\\python35'
New python executable in C:\Users\Bob\Envs\mynew_env\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

How do I fix it?
I tried different slashes in the path to my python installation: backslashes, forward slashes, double backslashes, the result is always the same.

Comment: Did you try to use forward slashes ? `mkvirtualenv mynew_env --python=d:/python/python35/python.exe`

Comment: Yes, as I said, I get the same messages.

Comment: I have the same problem on Win10, but it seems like the enviroment is created and effectively functioning.

Comment: sparaflAsh, thank you for the answer. Must be the problem with virtualenvwrapper-win itself. I keep using them too. When you try to remove an environment with rmvirtualenv env_name, do you get a message that the directory is not empty? These are the two inconveniences that I've encountered by far.

Comment: same here in a Windows 10 VM on Virtualbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason on the windows version of virtualenvwrapper it appears that you need to specify the options before the name of the environment, so you should initialise it as below:

```
mkvirtualenv --python=d:\python\python35\python.exe  mynew_env
```

Comment: Thats the answer.

Comment: I switched to Debian and cannot check it now, but I'll rely upon Tset Noitamotua's approval.